# How do I add a boolean parameter to Parse REST request with Restsharp?

Tags: c#, rest, parsing, restsharp

I use the nodechef Parse as a back-end server. I have an object like this:

```
 public class UserJson
    {
        ...
        public string myEmail { get; set; }
        public bool needsEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

I use REST for communication with the back-end server and Restsharp to construct my requests. I want to update "myEmail" field which is string. I write this:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.PUT;
request.AddParameter("myEmail", "mygmail@gmail.com");
```

my request goes OK, I get an OK response.
But if want to update a boolean field like "needsEmail" I write this:

```
request.AddParameter("needsEmail", false);
```

and I get a BadRequest response from the back-end server Parse. My question is:
How do I update a boolean value with Restsharp

Comment: send the boolean as a string "false" or 0 and dump what the server parses as a value!

Comment: found: https://www.parse.com/questions/a-boolean-data-type

Comment: I am sending the value as a REST request so the link is not useful. Also, I tried sending it as a string, did not work either

Comment: what does the servers receiving method look like?

Comment: I do not know, it is a nodechef server (they took over the Parse business).

Answer (score 2):

Using...

```
request.AddParameter("myEmail", "mygmail@gmail.com");
request.AddParameter("needsEmail", false);
```

Sends this to the server...

```
{ "myEmail" : "mygmail@gmail.com", "needsEmail": "false" }
```

If sending false as a string is not what the server wants/expects, you can add your parameters this way..

```
var body = new { myEmail = "mygmail@gmail.com", needsEmail = false };
request.AddJsonBody(body);
```

Which will send...

```
{ "myEmail" : "mygmail@gmail.com", "needsEmail": false }
```

This might make the server happy in your case.

Comment: yes correct, this is really helpful.